# Why does a moved class object not trigger the move constructor when bound to function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics

Lets say

- I have a non-trivial class object `A` that defines a copy and move constructor
- I move this object to a function which takes either `A` or `A&&`

Now in case of `foo`'s parameter type being `A`, the move constructor is called (this is to be expected as `A&&` is passed as an argument to the function-local A).

But in case of `A&&`, the move constructor is *not* called, and in fact no constructor is called. Why?

I would have assumed that this happens because of copy elision, but it also happens with the -O0 flag set for gcc. I also thought that && basically just `flags` an rvalue for overload resolution in the parameter list because inside the function body, it is treated as an lvalue. But this would mean that an lvalue `A` would bind a moved `A&&` and the move constructor should be called once again. What am I missing?

[CODE](https://godbolt.org/z/6adox4sMv)

Compiled under x86-x64 gcc 11.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

struct A
{
    char * str_;
    A() {
        std::cout << "normal constructor called\n";
        str_ = new char[7];
        sprintf(str_, "Hello!");
    }
    ~A(){ delete[] str_; }

    A(A& copy) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called\n";
        str_ = strdup(copy.str_);
    }

    A(A&& moved) {
        std::cout << "move constructor called\n";
        str_ = moved.str_;
        moved.str_ = nullptr;
    }
};


void foo(A&& a)
{
    std::cout << a.str_ << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    A obj;

    foo(std::move(obj));
}
```

Comment: because foo takes by reference

Comment: @Sopel: Ahhh. I'm probably tired. I remember you can do `int&& a = 5;` as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `foo` takes `A&&`, you are binding to a r-value reference and not making any new `A` objects that need construction.
This is because `std::move` is basically just a cast to r-value reference.
When `foo` takes `A`, you are passing a r-value reference to `A` as a means of constructing `A`. Here, the move constructor is chosen as it takes `A&&` as its argument.